# laptop keep freezing , then have to cold shutdown, please help

Tags: freeze, hardware, ubuntu-drivers, thunderbolt, pcie

Recently my Ubuntu 20.04 freezes after using it sometimes (for 10-20 mins), and then I have to force shutdown.
I am using Ubuntu 20.04 on my Dell Inspiron 7501 (dual boot with Windows). The system has a Nvidia GTX 1650 Ti graphic card and Thunderbolt.
I updated bios and all drivers from Dell Support, but the problem still exists.
On running the hardware diagnostic test of Dell support, I am getting everything passed except -

```
thunderbolt(TM) Controller -15E8 (Result-failure) , 
PCIeStatus (Result-failure),
Intel(R) USB 3.1 eXtensible Host Controller -1.10 (Microsoft) (Result-failure).
```

On the reading system log, I am getting this(attached below).

[system log after updating from dell support(in windows)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znjrx.png)
[system log initially](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AODB9.jpg)

Also, a symbol is popping on the right corner of my screen, attaching it down below.

[left most icon with plug and three dot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Scdac.jpg)

Comment: It appears that you have a number of problems here If it helps, research indicates that you may be suffering from a [long standing bug with the NVIDIA 1650Ti ](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/bug-cant-change-power-state-from-d3cold-to-d0-config-space-inaccessible-stuck-at-boot/112912/12) A suggested workaround is: Add “modprobe.blacklist=nvidia” on the kernel command line before it boots.

Comment: It still didn't solved my problem. I did block Nvidia gpu and in gpumanager log in var/log it is mentioning nvidia blacklisted

Comment: based on the output from Dell support it looks like you have a board level hardware problem. Do you have similar errors in the logs on the alternative dual boot?

Comment: Are you using the proprietary NV drivers or the open source nuveau? You should be using the proprietary one.

Comment: @ElderGeek i guess those dell support outputs were glitch as when i run these tests later they passed and not a single error came . In my ubuntu log it  is showing that power state is not able to come from d3cold or d3hot to d0 and after few attempts whole system get completely freeze.

Comment: @MatiasNGoldberg I am using  proprietary NV drivers only. Please tell me if you want any other log output screenshot or additional information to help me on this . For now i am doing my work on windows and have kept ubuntu in dual boot aside , but the problem still persist and i am not facing any problems while on windows , so I don't think so it is a hardware problem .

Comment: Then I don't know much to tell you. It could be anything. I can advise you to try forcing the performance scaling_governor on the CPU and see if it stops freezing after that.

Comment: @sj369 I'll ask again. Do you find similar errors in the logs from the Windows side of your dual boot system?